# Convert Unix Timestamps into a date

Tags: swift, unix, timestamp

So I have a huge file of Unix Timestamps and I would like to convert these into a date.

This is how my .txt file looks.

```
1529837880,xx.xx,xx.
1529837940,xx.xx,xx.
1529838000,xx.xx,xx.
1529838060,xx.xx,xx.
1529838120,xx.xx,xx.
```

I already created a string that stores all these numbers.

**the format I want should look like this:**

```
20130616 060300;xx.xx,xx. // 2013 06 16 - 06:03
20130616 060400;xx.xx,xx.
20130616 060500;xx.xx,xx.
20130616 060600;xx.xx,xx.
20130616 060700;xx.xx,xx.
20130616 060800;xx.xx,xx.
```

my string looks like this

```
var str = """

    1529837880,xx.xx,xx.
    1529837940,xx.xx,xx.
    1529838000,xx.xx,xx.
    1529838060,xx.xx,xx.
    1529838120,xx.xx,xx.

"""
```

So how would I do this?

Comment: When reviewing the answers in the duplicate be sure you look at the ones using `Date` and not the older ones using `NSDate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780353-init) to convert a Unix timestamp (represented as a `TimeInterval` aka `Double`) into a `Date` value.

The second step would then be to create and configure a suitable [`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) to output the date as a string in your desired format (using the [`DateFormatter.string(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1415810-string) method).

Comment: so you mean `str.Date.init(NSTimeIntervalSince1970)` ? because im getting a error: `value of type 'String' has no member 'Date'`